# What visas do Vietnamese and Americans require for travelling to New Zealand from Australia?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, new-zealand, visa-free-entry, vietnamese-citizens

I am a Vietnamese citizen about to travel to New Zealand this coming July. I'm currently holding an Australian student visa.

Am I required to apply for a tourist visa in order to enter New Zealand?

Also, my friend who is going to accompany me is a US citizen, will be entering Australia via ETA.

Does she need to apply for a tourist visa for New Zealand?

Comment: What nationality are you two?

Comment: I am vietnamese and my friend is american

Answer (score 8):

As stated by Timatic, the database used by airlines, [Americans do **not** need a visa for New Zealand.](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=vn&DE=nz&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=au&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX)

> Visa required, **except** for Nationals of USA for a maximum stay
>   of 3 months.

As for [Vietnamese](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=vn&DE=nz&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=au&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX):

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a valid "Authority
>   to Return", **or** a permanent residence visa, **or** a resident return
>   visa issued by Australia, permitting an indefinite stay in'
>   Australia.

So if you hold any of these documents, you can enter without a visa. Otherwise, you need a visa

Comment: @LinhLe If this answer satisfies you, please upvote and accept it (by clicking on the button below the down arrow)